# jQuery.ajax rest post equivlent in C#

Tags: jquery, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a rest post using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://graylogurl/gelf',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{"short_message":"test message", "host":"localhost", "facility":"ajax", "_environment":"dev", "_meme":"yolo", "full_message":"this will contain a longer message"}',
                type: 'POST'
            });
```

This post correctly and works for what I need. I've tried to do a similar thing in my MVC4 controller using C#

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graylogurl/gelf");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"short_message\":\"test message\", \"host\":\"localhost\", \"facility\":\"ajax\", \"_environment\":\"dev\", \"_meme\":\"yolo\", \"full_message\":\"this is from the controller\"}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Unfortunately, it always times out. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
```

With the correct content type:

```
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Also make sure you have wrapped IDisposable resources in `using` statements and using a `WebClient` and a proper JSON serializer to build your JSON string seems easier and more correct:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        short_message = "test message",
        host = "localhost",
        facility = "ajax",
        _environment = "dev",
        _meme = "yolo",
        full_message = "this is from the controller",
    });
    var resultData = client.UploadData("https://graylogurl/gelf", Encoding.UTF8.GeBytes(data));
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultData);
}
```

Also make sure that the server on which you hosted your ASP.NET application has access to the remote url you are trying to access and that there are no firewalls blocking it. Contact your network administrator if you have some doubts but in order to be able to perform this HTTP request the remote url must be accessible over the 443 port (HTTPS) from the web server on which your application is hosted.